# Encryption of mail from Exchange is unreadable.

Tags: python, email, gnupg

I've been doing a lot of work with gpg-mailgate lately to the point where I have it working the way I want. I ran across an issue today that I'm not sure what is going on.

Email coming in from an an exchange server hits mailgate and gets deilvered as unreadable junk.

> h�hi�¤��u,fA�����@õ�YvΑ�+���u��U)
>   ��x�'�'y��PԎ���|��]����J�ϧ�D���E`�{���b#>_�I��r~+*X^�����GlĀ���+�S�p�W`0h+�G��)B��MZW`0Dhc�+#�q�a8�7%���������,�H���v�L������X̢2�� J�sڒ��k��W�<�30^�YUw}I�в��/�91���x)��Q ��0D�a

Is what I get.  No clue why.

```
Date: Sun, 22 Sep 2013 05:25:12 -0400
Subject: Exchange test
Thread-Topic: Exchange test
Thread-Index: Ac63daSA+YXi7iiQR4Wy3htLwjbA7A==
Message-ID: <E7E690AD15261D4CAC417490E3C654587B1D6C869C@mail.compassnetworkgroup.com>
Accept-Language: en-US
Content-Language: en-US
X-MS-Has-Attach:
X-MS-TNEF-Correlator:
acceptlanguage: en-US
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
MIME-Version: 1.0
QW5vdGhlciB0ZXN0DQoNClNlbnQgZnJvbSBteSBBbmRyb2lkIHBob25lIHVzaW5nIFRvdWNoRG93
biAod3d3Lm5pdHJvZGVzay5jb20pDQo=
```

The headers don't look that out of the ordinary except for the TNEF additions.  I've been writing the raw data to a log before mailgate even begins it's work just to track this down.

Here is the code for mailgate.

http://pastebin.com/ywSPQKij

I can add to this that I'm sending from a mobile client that is set to plain.  If i do this from outlook set to plan it works.  The headers differ:

```
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="us-ascii"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
```

That still doesn't answer why it outputs garbage thogh.  Other emails coming through as base64, utf-8 are just fine.

Comment: The program you posted seems to encrypt messages. The point of encryption is to produce “unreadable junk”, which is then somehow decrypted. Can you tell us how do you decrypt them, i.e. how do you check if it “works” or “outputs garbage”?

Comment: @VasiliyFaronov It works when I get an decryptable messsage, as I do with all other messages coming through the system.   They are decrypted either in the webmail client ( roundcube ) , sylpheed, k9 or the command line depending on where I am sitting at the moment.  I'm aware of the point of encryption, the above output is not normal output hence my question.